# Get total number of records in sql query without considering limits

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 100 records in a sql table

can I get the total number of records in single query with limits applied

like ..

```
SELECT * , COUNT(*) as records form table offset 0 limit 10.
```

So the records will have value 100. 
Is possible some how ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT(*)
            from table) as records 
form table 
offset 0 limit 10;
```

But it would be better to do only one separate query for this count, then from your front end application display it the way you want, instead of doing it 100 times.

Comment: ok but my concern was about performance. However It is better syntactically then running separate query

Comment: @RupeshPatel I am guessing you are doing a pagination from php, in this case do only on query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` and do a pagination query using the `LIMIT` without count then take this value coming from the query that contains count and display it separately, this will be better than doing it 100 times.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal yes I am developing a pagination plugin for zf2. I got it , I ask because just in case I am missing some thing